how to run custom sql in directus flow "run script" block / how to create run sql block
i tried to find how to run a custom sql in directus flow.
there is udpate data / get data / delete data blocks, but there isnt a run sql blcok.
any idea how to run custom sql in script block or how to create a run sql blcok ?
